# how to run cxf jax-ws without build-in jetty (use tomcat instead)

Tags: tomcat, jetty, jax-ws, cxf

every time when i run with the following inside tomcat, cxf build-in jetty is up and serving the request.

```
<jaxws:endpoint 
    id="wsServer"
    implementor="a.b.c.ServiceImpl"
    address="http://localhost:8080/ws">
</jaxws:endpoint>
```

is there any way we have tomcat receiving the request and delegating to cxf?

Comment: Take a look [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9486835/wadl-generation-tool.
It seems relevant to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**

You can avoid using embedded Jetty by following [this article](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/servlet-transport.html): Use `org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet` in your web.xml and don't forget to [import `META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7098734/267197).

Alternatively (if CXF is not your must) you can:

- [Use `WSServletContextListener` and `WSServlet`](http://www.centurion.link/w/programming/java/web_service#deployment_to_tomcat_server). In this approach WS endpoints are listed in `sun-jaxws.xml` file.
- [Use Spring-WS](http://www.centurion.link/w/programming/java/web_service#implementing_a_jax-ws_service_using_spring_jax-ws). In this case you describe your endpoints in Spring context.