# Getting the Jetty instance from Spring Web Service

Tags: java, spring, jetty, jax-ws, cxf

I am creating a web service with spring + jetty + cxf using the following:

```
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml" />
<jaxws:endpoint id="helloWorld" implementor="com.test.EndpointImp" address="http://localhost:9002/test">
</jaxws:endpoint>
```

This all works as expected and very well. Now I need to "serve" some servlets. Is there anyway I can get to the jetty Server instance that is created for this, so that I can add the servlets? I dont want to create another Jetty instance on another port just for the servlets I need to use.

Any information will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think [my post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8866816/267197) is relevant to your problem. In particular follow [this article](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/servlet-transport.html) which shows how to have several servlets.

Comment: Thats perfect. Post an answer so I can mark it as correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution you are looking for is described in [this article](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/servlet-transport.html). The key points (which I also mentioned in [my post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8866816/267197)) are to use `org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet` in your `web.xml`, don't forget to import `META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml` (you did so) and also use relative `address="/myservice"` attribute. In this case CXF routines will not launch embedded Jetty but use this servlet for processing the inbound requests.

Comment: Definitely the best way to go about it

Answer (score -1):

Of course a webapp can handle at the same time some WebServices and servlets.

I suppose your web services are in a web application.
Thus you should have a web.xml (in WEB-INF). You can add your servlets declarations in this web.xml.

Jetty should start your webapp.

We can't help you more if you don't give us more details of your project (Maven based or not, how do you launch Jetty, etc...).

Comment: I will gladly give you more details, what would you like to know? Thats all I have in my spring config file. My applications is launched as standalone and not in a web container.